# Computer restarting randomly

Tags: windows, reboot

For the last couple of days Windows 10 restarts randomly after every couple of minutes. Sometimes it gets into a loop and restarts again before even completing the previous start up.

I have unsuccessfully tried the following to solve this issue:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling a fresh Windows 10
2. Unplugging all the USB devices
3. Removing the RAM modules, cleaning the slots, and leaving in only one module (plus changing the RAM slot used)
4. Cleaning the PC with a blower
5. Removing one of the two hard drives
6. Running diagnostics (where everything passed)

I don't know what to do now.

Note: Booting in Safe Mode, Windows 10 works fine, with no restarting.

Comment: in what I had already experienced, it might indicate some hardware / driver problems. The fact that on safe mode it's working fine, should that a faulty driver or piece of hardware or special functionality of a hardware doesn't get used in safe mode. It also could mean that your computer power supply is not good enough and can't power all of your equipment. 
this could happens if you have a high power graphic card, for instance.
Not sure enough to make that comment a clear answer, however.

Comment: Could youu give more details ? Seems like a desktop computer, not a laptop, right ?

Comment: The power supply rating (Wattage) and components used would be interesting to know. A friend of mine had a very similar issue, in his case it was a poor power supply.

Comment: My machine is Dell Precision T3500, 16 GB Ram, 2 Hard Disk (1 Tb and 500 Gb) Respectly and Graphics card is EVGA Nvidia gtx 1050 ti (4-GB)

Comment: That comes with a 525W power supply and an Intel Xeon 5600 Series CPU. Should be sufficient to me.

Comment: Futhermore I am using this pc from starting of this year January it was working fine till the last couple of days if power supply was not enough I cannot be able to use till now

Comment: In most cases windows behave like that if there two things happened: 1-some bad sector on a hard drive and second is an issue with RAM. I suggest you to run GSmartControl and check SMART attributes 5, 196, 197 (if there values greater than zero, then it is HDD fault), run also long SMART test with GSmartControl. Other thing to do is to run memtest86 for at least 3 successful passes

Comment: @Alex I have run Gsmartcontrol software as you suggested and following are the result 

500 GB Hard DISK

https://ibb.co/cVGffp

https://ibb.co/h3GkD9

https://ibb.co/kdtXt9

1 TB Hard disk


https://ibb.co/dKywmU

https://ibb.co/kTgct9

Comment: After running Gsmartcontrol:
In 500 GB hard disk the attributes 197 and 198 is greater than zero (both are 8) and also highlighted in pink while the 196 attribute is not present in hard disk. 

In 1 TB hard disk the attributes 5,197 are zero while 196 attribute is missing

Comment: So, that is defiantly the case why windows behave like that. My advise is to save most important data ASAP and replace failed HDD. You can try to repair HDD by forcing internal firmware to replace broken sectors from spare area with low level hdd tools, but if it start failing, no more trust to such hard drive

Comment: I have remove the 500 gb hard disk while on 1 tb hard drive I installed the fresh windows the problem still occur the system is still restarting

Comment: Here,s the graphics specification (Gpu-Z)

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU-Z ) the results are below:


https://ibb.co/cnort9


https://ibb.co/jy7Ufp


https://ibb.co/moK36U

https://ibb.co/i2e36U

Answer (score 0):

I think in the safe mode, windows system just loads a little driver. My instinct tells me that the problem has something with the video driver. Tried to delete the driver.

Also monitor the temperature of CPU and graphics card. Does it exceeds the upper limit.

Comment: I have installed the latest driver for the video card available on the internet from the manufacturer/vendor site but the problem still exist

Comment: Based on windows 7 cpu meter gadget Cpu usage is 1 or below 1 while the Ram usage is 9. For the graphics card temperature I don't know where to look

Comment: not necessarily the latest driver, you need a stable one. Uninstall the driver, let see if it can work smoothly without the driver.

Comment: Windows 10 automatically update driver if driver is not installed. Before I have updated latest driver from the internet I was using Windows default driver which windows installed on it,s own

Comment: shutdown the update. just have a try.

Comment: Still no luck I have disable the graphics card driver from device manager and restart pc for the changing to take effect but my pc is still restarting after sometime

Comment: Try win7. or install a Linux to make a double boot system to see if the hardware goes wrong.

Comment: I have already tried windows 7 still no luck the issue is still there while for Linux I don't have any bootable usb of linux or nor I can,t make due to rebooting issue

Comment: Here,s the graphics specification (Gpu-Z)


(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU-Z ) the results are below


https://ibb.co/cnort9



https://ibb.co/jy7Ufp




https://ibb.co/moK36U



https://ibb.co/i2e36U

Comment: I have also tested Ubuntu distro now but the problem still there the system is still rebooting

Comment: It seems that you have problems with your hardware.

Comment: I have run the diagnosis which shows everything is pass

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I was to unable to solve this issue therefore I have changed my machine which is working fine now. 
Following are the update of steps which I have unsuccessfully tried the solve this issue:

1) I have change the power supply

2) I have change operating system from windows to Linux Ubuntu

3) I have asked this above question in another website forum and follow the members suggestions ( https://forums.techguy.org/threads/computer-restarting-randomly.1214471/ )